# beginPath and ctx.arc in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make drawing board. I'm using `ctx.beginPath()` and to smooth out the edges I added `ctx.arc()` and `ctx.fill()`. But the problem is that if I move mouse too quickly it's not drawing continues line. It draws circles with spaces between them. The greater speed of the mouse, the greater are the spaces between circles. Here's my `JS` code:

```
var lastX;
var lastY;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    if (isMouseDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        if (mode == "pen") { //This is drawing mode (The problem is here)
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            ctx.arc(lastX, lastY, y, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);  //y is just strokes width
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        } else {  //This is eraser
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
            ctx.arc(lastX, lastY, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
        }
        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the normal behavior. Movement isn't continuous, it's frame-by-frame. If you want "continuous" movement, you'll need to draw circles pixel by pixel between potentially distant mouse points from one frame to the next. One of the easiest ways to do this is to detach the circle position from the mouse position and have it "follow" the mouse pixel by pixel (or with fine enough granularity that it appears continuous), but it's not clear if this behavior would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Draw a path

Rather than draw an arc draw a path with a lineWidth

Set the `ctx.lineWidth` to the radius of the circle * 2. For end points set `ctx.lineCap = "round"` and for corners set `ctx.lineJoin = "round"`

### Basic example

Click drag on canvas to draw.

```js
const points = [];
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvents);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseEvents);
function mouseEvents(e){
    mouse.x = e.pageX - 1;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - 1;
    const lb = mouse.button;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
  if (mouse.button) {
      if (!lb) { points.length = 0 }
      points.push({x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y});
      drawPoints();
  } 
}
function drawPoints() {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.lineWidth = 20;
   ctx.lineCap = "round";
   ctx.lineJoin = "round";
   ctx.beginPath();
   for (const p of points) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y); }
   ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas { 
   position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px;
   cursor: crosshair;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```